# No Raspberry Pi - but blue sky

Tags: electrical-engineering, control-engineering

Is there a platform/framework other than Raspberry Pi that:

- has excellent documentation (open-source is a plus)
- does not have commercially prohibitive licences (ideally close to [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/open-source-misses-the-point.en.html))
- is able to interface with almost any device, like the Raspberry Pi
- provides technical possibilities similar to those of Raspberry Pi (e.g. I can easily make a doorbell that sends me email of someone presses it); I guess this entails that it should come with an OS, since I'm most comfortable with Python. I think Arduino would therefore not fit the bill?

I read good things about the Beaglebone, but I'm not sure what the general opinion is on that. The reason I'm not happy with Raspberry Pi is that I've [read](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=24520397) that  is not open source and that there are some problems around open sourcing it or using it commercially

Comment: asking for opinions is off topic here ... shopping questions are also off topic, so you can ask to confirm the existence of a product, but you cannot ask which product

Comment: Your second link doesn’t seem to be related to commercialization issues.